# Cast all text inside XmlDocument to lower case

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xls

I've got a function, which returns XmlDocument in the loaded form, and I haven't got the access to the source. What I need to do is something a keen to:

```
a=text.ToLowerInvariant();
xmlDoc.Load(a);
```

but in reverse

```
xmlDoc.Load(text);
var workingDocument=xmlDoc.ToLower();//ToLower(this XmlNode) is the function I need
```

I understand that ToLowerInvariant will also cast the attribute values to lower, as well as text inside xml nodes, and this is the intended behavior.

Is there any way to accomplish this without having to recursively iterate through all the nodes and attributes inside xmlDoc?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to run case insensitive xpath queries on the document content without having to use the translate function all the time

Comment: I thought as much. Do you have a an actual performance bottleneck becasue of that?

Comment: Not really. I don't want to use translate because it makes the queries unreadable, and I can do the recursive enumeration thing, but I'm curious if there is a better way of doing this. This is probably not the last time I have to do something similar with XmlDocument, I might as well learn something

Answer (score 2):

If you really really want it, you can always do:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlDoc.OuterXml.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is just the legibility of the XPath expression you are worried about, you can abstract that away a little bit:

```
var keyword = "A Keyword";

var nodes1 = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(String.Format("//foo[{0}]", XPathValueContains(keyword)));
var nodes2 = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(String.Format("//foo[{0}]", XPathValueEquals(keyword)));
```

where `XPathValueContains()` and `XPathValueEquals()` are:

```
public static string XPathValueContains(string input)  
{  
    return String.Format(
        "contains(translate(., {0}, {1}), {1})",
        XPathEscapeString( input.ToUpperInvariant() ), 
        XPathEscapeString( input.ToLowerInvariant() )
    );
}

public static string XPathValueEquals(string input)  
{  
    return String.Format(
        "translate(., {0}, {1}) = {1}",
        XPathEscapeString( input.ToUpperInvariant() ), 
        XPathEscapeString( input.ToLowerInvariant() )
    );
}
```

and `XPathEscapeString()` a function to deal with embedded single quotes which is defined as:

```
public static string XPathEscapeString(string input)  
{  
    if (input.Contains("'"))
    {
        return "concat('" + String.Join("', \"'\", '", input.Split('\'')) + "')";
    }
    else 
    {
        return "'" + input + "'";
    }
}
```